# Deep Convolutional Autoencoder Using a single Core

Tags: theano, keras

I'm going through the Keras autoencoder tutorial on [this link](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) and I noticed that, while all previous examples used all available cores on my machine, the example for the **Convolutional autoencoder** used a **single core**, therefore taking quite a bit longer than the previous examples.

I've trained it used the theano backend (as opposed to using tensorflow as suggested in the tutorial) though.

Is this expected behaviour or is something wrong here?